# Can't Get Git to use insteadOf on Submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm running Git 2.18.0 and I'm trying to get Git to use an ssh:// urls on a repository whose original .gitmodule file uses file:// urls

I've got this in `.git/config`:

````
submodule.dut/dev.git.active=true
submodule.dut/dev.git.url=file:///wv/mcs/tedd/repo_lib/dev.git
submodule.dut/locations.git.active=true
url.ssh://orw-tucker-vm/wv/mcs/tedd/repo_lib.insteadof=file:///wv/mcs/tedd/repo_lib```

Then I do:

```bash
% git submodule sync
% git submodule update --init
````

But I get errors:

```
Cloning into '/home/rsalemi/workspaces/tedd_tb/dut/dev.git'...
fatal: '/wv/mcs/tedd/repo_lib/dev.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'file:///wv/mcs/tedd/repo_lib/dev.git' into submodule path '/home/rsalemi/workspaces/tedd_tb/dut/dev.git' failed
Failed to clone 'dut/dev.git' a second time, aborting
```

Git appears to be ignoring the insteadof configuration entry.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I used `git config --local` but turns out I needed `git config --global`